# Populate a combox with many names after formatting them

Tags: c#, string, linq, data-binding, linq-to-entities

Okay I have something that looks like this:

Company Name-1234

I only want the name to be in the combobox for the user to select because the dash followed by a number is not neccessary to have in this case.

Heres my code to query the database with Linq to entites and then remove the everything after the dash but it dosent seem to be populating the combobox with anything.

```
            using (context ctx = new context())
            {
            List<companyinformation> compInf = new List<companyinformation>();

            var getCompanies = (from c in ctx.companyinformations
                               select c.name).ToList();

            foreach (var n in getCompanies)
            {
                compInf.Add(new companyinformation() { name = Remove(n.LastIndexOf('-')) });
            }

            cbModClient.DataSource = compInf;
            cbModClient.DisplayMember = "name";
            cbModClient.SelectedIndex = -1;
            };
```

I just tried this code and it worked perfrectly, I'm think its because I used "-" instead of '-' this time.

```
        using (context ctx = new context())
        {
            List<companyinformation> compInf = new List<companyinformation>(ctx.companyinformations);

            var getCompanies = (from c in compInf
                       where c.name.Contains("-")
                       select c.name.Substring(0, c.name.LastIndexOf("-"))).ToList();

            cbModClient.DataSource = getCompanies;
            cbModClient.DisplayMember = "name";
            cbModClient.SelectedIndex = -1;
        };
```

Comment: You're setting the combo box's DataSource to the original data, not the newly created List. Perhaps if you used more descriptive variable names, you would make fewer mistakes like this ;)

Comment: Well I have been changing so mayn things and trying everything i can think of that this was a simple typo, but I changed it to CompInf and it still does not populate anything!

Comment: Are you certain that the query returns data?

Comment: yes absolutely sure, just tested it.

Comment: What is Remove method in `Remove(n.LastIndexOf('-'))` doing? It does not get current n as parameter. Also, are you sure that each company name contains a dash? `LastIndexOf` returns -1 if unsuccessful, probably cutting the company names short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're binding to the `getCompanies` result collection, but you've performed the string operations and added those to `compInf`.

```
cbModClient.DataSource = compInf;
```

Perhaps a shorter way:

```
var companyNames = ctx.companyinformations
                      .Select(c=> new {FormattedName = 
                                 c.name.Substring(0,c.name.LastIndexOf('-'))
                                       .Trim()})
                      .ToList();

cbModClient.DataSource = companyNames;
cbModClient.DisplayMember = "FormattedName";
cbModClient.ValueMember = "FormattedName";
```

Consider putting a breakpoint on the DataSource assignment, and inspect/ensure that your variable indeed has the values that you expect. That'll determine whether your problem is LINQ related, or databinding related.

Comment: I tried this and still no luck :( the combobox still has nothing in it's list.

Comment: Thanks, using .Substring instead of .Remove made this a lot cleaner!

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to duplicate the "Still no items appearing" problem. Here is an equivalent program that works.

Assuming that you do get a result from the database and no exceptions are being thrown, the question remaining is: How is your ComboBox different?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Form1 : Form
{
    class CompanyInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    static string RemoveTrailingDash(string value)
    {
        int dashIndex = value.LastIndexOf('-');
        if (dashIndex > 0)
            return value.Substring(0, dashIndex).TrimEnd();
        return value;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        var companies = new CompanyInfo[]
        {
            new CompanyInfo { Name = "Ajax - 1200" },
            new CompanyInfo { Name = "Bermuda Corp - 1" },
            new CompanyInfo { Name = "Capitol Inc" },
            new CompanyInfo { Name = "Dash LLC - " },
        };

        Controls.Add(new ComboBox
        {
            Location = new Point(10, 10),
            DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList,

            DataSource = companies.Select(c => new { FormattedName = RemoveTrailingDash(c.Name) }).ToList(),
            DisplayMember = "FormattedName",
        });
    }
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Comment: @MDL I edited this to more closely reflect your data, and to not crash if there is no dash.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, for some reason it worked when I used "-" instead of '-'